# How to reauthenticate API in loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to pull data from Azure API.
When I get a response from API we get next link in API response as well.
So in first loop I am pulling data from first page and then in second loop I am pulling data till nextlink is not present in response.

But when script is running for a long time it will pull half data for a subscription and API token
will expire.

How can I do authentication again and pull data for the particular subscription.

```
subscriptions=pd.read_csv("subscriptionid.csv")
for subscription in subscriptions['subsid']:
    print(subscription)

    access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')
    endpoint ="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+subscription+"/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$expand=meterDetails,additionalProperties&$filter=properties/usageStart eq '2022-04-01' and properties/usageEnd eq '2022-04-30'&metric=AmortizedCost&api-version=2019-05-01"
    print(endpoint)
    headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token}
    #---------------------------------------making request---------------------------------------------------------------------
    json_output= requests.get(endpoint,headers=headers).json()
    #-----------------------------------------pulling data----------------------------------------------------------------------
    frame=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range (len(json_output['value'])):


        df1= pd.DataFrame(data={
            'id':json_output['value'][i].setdefault('id','Not Present'),
            'name':json_output['value'][i].setdefault('name','Not Present'),
            'type':json_output['value'][i].setdefault('type','Not Present'),
            'tags':str(json_output['value'][i].setdefault('tags','Not Present')),
            'billingAccountId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingAccountId','Not Present'),
            'billingAccountName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingAccountName','Not Present'),
            'billingPeriodStartDate':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingPeriodStartDate','Not Present'),
            'billingPeriodEndDate':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingPeriodEndDate','Not Present'),
            'billingProfileId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingProfileId','Not Present'),
            'billingProfileName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingProfileName','Not Present'),
            'accountOwnerId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('accountOwnerId','Not Present'),
            'accountName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('accountName','Not Present'),
            'subscriptionId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('subscriptionId','Not Present'),
            'subscriptionName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('subscriptionName','Not Present'),
            'date':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('date','Not Present'),
            'product':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('product','Not Present'),
            'partNumber':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('partNumber','Not Present'),
            'meterId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('meterId','Not Present'),
            'quantity':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('quantity','Not Present'),
            'effectivePrice':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('effectivePrice','Not Present'),
            'cost':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('cost','Not Present'),
            'unitPrice':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('unitPrice','Not Present'),
            'billingCurrency':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingCurrency','Not Present'),
            'resourceLocation':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceLocation','Not Present'),
            'consumedService':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('consumedService','Not Present'),
            'resourceId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceId','Not Present'),
            'resourceName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceName','Not Present'),
            'invoiceSection':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('invoiceSection','Not Present'),
            'resourceGroup':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceGroup','Not Present'),
            'offerId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('offerId','Not Present'),
            'isAzureCreditEligible':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('isAzureCreditEligible','Not Present'),
            'publisherType':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('publisherType','Not Present'),
            'chargeType':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('chargeType','Not Present'),
            'frequency':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('frequency','Not Present'),
            'meterName':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('meterName','Not Present'),
            'meterCategory':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('meterCategory','Not Present'),
            'meterSubCategory':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('meterSubCategory','Not Present'),
            'unitOfMeasure':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('unitOfMeasure','Not Present'),
            'serviceInfo2':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('serviceInfo2','Not Present'),
            'reservationId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('reservationId','Not Present'),
            'reservationName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('reservationName','Not Present'),
            'term':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('term','Not Present')

        },index=[i])

        frame=frame.append(df1)

    print("condition1")


    # Retrieve price list from all available pages until there is no 'NextPageLink' available to retrieve prices  
    try:
        while("nextLink" in json_output):

            #context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authentication_endpoint + tenant_id)
            #token_response = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource, application_id, application_secret)


            access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')
          #  print(access_token)
            #print(access_token)
            headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token}
            json_output = requests.get(json_output["nextLink"],headers=headers,).json()        
            for i in range (len(json_output['value'])):


                df2= pd.DataFrame(data={
                'id':json_output['value'][i].setdefault('id','Not Present'),
                'name':json_output['value'][i].setdefault('name','Not Present'),
                'type':json_output['value'][i].setdefault('type','Not Present'),
                'tags':str(json_output['value'][i].setdefault('tags','Not Present')),
                'billingAccountId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingAccountId','Not Present'),
                'billingAccountName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingAccountName','Not Present'),
                'billingPeriodStartDate':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingPeriodStartDate','Not Present'),
                'billingPeriodEndDate':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingPeriodEndDate','Not Present'),
                'billingProfileId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingProfileId','Not Present'),
                'billingProfileName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingProfileName','Not Present'),
                'accountOwnerId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('accountOwnerId','Not Present'),
                'accountName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('accountName','Not Present'),
                'subscriptionId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('subscriptionId','Not Present'),
                'subscriptionName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('subscriptionName','Not Present'),
                'date':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('date','Not Present'),
                'product':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('product','Not Present'),
                'partNumber':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('partNumber','Not Present'),
                'meterId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('meterId','Not Present'),
                'quantity':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('quantity','Not Present'),
                'effectivePrice':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('effectivePrice','Not Present'),
                'cost':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('cost','Not Present'),
                'unitPrice':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('unitPrice','Not Present'),
                'billingCurrency':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('billingCurrency','Not Present'),
                'resourceLocation':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceLocation','Not Present'),
                'consumedService':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('consumedService','Not Present'),
                'resourceId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceId','Not Present'),
                'resourceName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceName','Not Present'),
                'invoiceSection':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('invoiceSection','Not Present'),
                'resourceGroup':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('resourceGroup','Not Present'),
                'offerId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('offerId','Not Present'),
                'isAzureCreditEligible':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('isAzureCreditEligible','Not Present'),
                'publisherType':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('publisherType','Not Present'),
                'chargeType':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('chargeType','Not Present'),
                'frequency':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('frequency','Not Present'),
                'meterName':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('meterName','Not Present'),
                'meterCategory':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('meterCategory','Not Present'),
                'meterSubCategory':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('meterSubCategory','Not Present'),
                'unitOfMeasure':json_output['value'][i]['properties']['meterDetails'].setdefault('unitOfMeasure','Not Present'),
                'serviceInfo2':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('serviceInfo2','Not Present'),
                'reservationId':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('reservationId','Not Present'),
                'reservationName':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('reservationName','Not Present'),
                'term':json_output['value'][i]['properties'].setdefault('term','Not Present')},index=[i])

                frame=frame.append(df2)

            print("condition2")
            frame.to_csv(subscription+".csv")
            temp=json_output['nextLink']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(temp)
```

Comment: just get the next token after every 3 pages (links pulled)

Comment: in the `for subscription in subscriptions['subsid']:` loop, just keep track and every 3rd request, get a new token, before you continue with the next inner loop

Comment: in df2 it is failing in df1 runs only once can you please help with the code @DeanVanGreunen

Comment: you need to get a new token in df1 and in df2

Comment: tried it it ran 30 min then failed there .i tried authenticating in loop but i failed because lot of authentication has been done in loop.

Comment: you might be getting rate limited

Comment: i suggest you do this in batches, split your code in batches and then try each batch one at a time, instead of 2 massive for loops

Comment: its getting stuck in one subscription  only how can i split one subscription